# Returning function values in C#

Tags: c#

I am working on a c# program that calculates gross pay, taxes, deduction and net pay using an input of name, hours worked, hourly rate and deduction code. I am having problems with one specific part. I cannot get my "GrossPay" function to return gross pay as an amount to show in my textbox. The function takes hours worked and hourly rate as parameters and multiplies them, assigns the result to gross pay, and then returns it. I'm not very good with C# syntax so I've been using the internet as a resource to try and write this code. Here is the code (incomplete) so far for this program.

```
 private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string employeeName = txtEmployeeName.Text;
        decimal hoursWorked = Decimal.Parse(txtHoursWorked.Text);
        decimal hourlyRate = Decimal.Parse(txtHourlyRate.Text);
        int deductionCode = Int32.Parse(txtDeductionCode.Text);
        GrossPay();
    }

    private void GrossPay(decimal hoursWorked, decimal hourlyRate)
    {
        decimal grossPay = hoursWorked * hourlyRate;    
        grossPay = Decimal.Parse(txtGrossPay.Text);
    }
```

Comment: try `private decimal GrossPay(...` and make the last statement `return grossPay;`

Comment: What's the question here?

Comment: `return (hoursWorked * hourlyRate);`  no real need for a temp var

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the return type set to `void`, which means that it doesn't return anything when it completes. In order to return something, you have to declare the type you're returning. Then before your function code would reach "the end", you have to return something (or throw an exception).

In this case, let's set the return type to `decimal` and return the `grossPay` variable, which is of type `decimal`. We also don't need to parse it from the TextBox, since you're passing it via the function parameters.

```
private decimal GrossPay(decimal hoursWorked, decimal hourlyRate)
{
    decimal grossPay = hoursWorked * hourlyRate;    
    return grossPay;
}
```

We can make this even shorter, since there's no need for the `grossPay` variable.

```
private decimal GrossPay(decimal hoursWorked, decimal hourlyRate)
{
    return hoursWorked * hourlyRate;    
}
```

Since this function doesn't seem to rely on any outside information, it'd probably be good to make it a static function so we don't have to have an instance of that class before calling the `GrossPay()` function.

```
private static decimal GrossPay(decimal hoursWorked, decimal hourlyRate)
{
    return hoursWorked * hourlyRate;    
}
```

Making it static allows you to call it like this:

```
decimal grossPay = MyCalculationUtilities.GrossPay(hoursWorked, hourlyRate);
```

Rather than this:

```
MyCalculationUtilities calculator = new MyCalculationUtilities();
decimalgrossPay = calculator.GrossPay(hoursWorked, hourlyRate);
```

One final suggestion, I suggest changing it from `GrossPay` to `CalculateGrossPay` as it's more descriptive of what the function actually does.